# "has many through" association in Sequelize

Tags: sequelize.js

Let's say we have three models:

- books
- chapters
- paragraphs

Here are their associations:

- **Books** have many **chapters**.
- **Chapters** have many **paragraphs**.
- **Books** have many **paragraphs**, through **chapters**.

**Is it possible to define a 'has many, through' relationship with Sequelize? If so, how?**

Here are very basic models for Book, Chapter, and Paragraph:

```
// Book model
const Book = sequelize.define('Book', {
  id: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    allowNull: false,
    primaryKey: true
  },
  title: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING
  }
}, {
  classMethods: {
    associate: (models) => {
      Book.hasMany(models.Chapter, {
        foreignKey: 'bookId',
        as: 'chapters'
      });
    }
    // How can you add an association for a book having many paragraphs, through chapters?
  }
});


// Chapter model
const Chapter = sequelize.define('Chapter', {
  id: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    allowNull: false,
    primaryKey: true
  },
  title: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING
  }
}, {
  classMethods: {
    associate: (models) => {
      Chapter.hasMany(models.Paragraph, {
        foreignKey: 'chapterId',
        as: 'paragraphs'
      });

      Chapter.belongsTo(models.Book, {
        foreignKey: 'bookId'
      });
    }
  }
});


// Paragraph Model
const Paragraph = sequelize.define('Paragraph', {
  id: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    allowNull: false,
    primaryKey: true
  },
  content: {
    type: DataTypes.TEXT
  }
}, {
  classMethods: {
    associate: (models) => {
      Paragraph.belongsTo(models.Chapter, {
        foreignKey: 'chapterId'
      });
    }
    // How can you add an association for paragraphs belonging to a book "through" chapters?
  }
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no such a possibility. What you can do is to create some `instanceMethods` on both `Book` and `Paragraph` model like `getParagraphs` and `getBook` in order to retrieve associated elements

```js
// in Book model
instanceMethods: {
    getParagraphs: function(options){
        options.include = [
            {
                model: sequelize.models.Chapter,
                attributes: [],
                where: {
                    bookId: this.get('id')
                }
            }
        ];

        return sequelize.models.Paragraph.findAll(options);
    }
}
```

Above method would return all paragraphs whose chapter belongs to specified book. And you could do the reverse for `getBook` in the `Paragraph` model.

On the other hand, in order to retrieve book with all it's chapters and their paragraphs, you would simply perform `findAll` with nested `include` (jest reminding about that).